# Using hobby package to plot bezier curves through a set of data points in a .dat file

Tags: pgfplots, hobby

I would like to use the `hobby` package to plot smooth drawn curves through points. `pgf`s' `smooth` function is not working properly. My code is a follows,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, every tick label/.append style={font=\normalsize}}


\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
    solid,smooth, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=white}, mark=triangle*\\%
    solid, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=black}, mark=triangle*\\%
    densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=white},mark=diamond*\\%
    densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=black}, mark=diamond*\\%
}

\begin{filecontents}{p2.dat}
SAT ETCY-5  ETCX-5  ETCY-10 ETCX-10 AR-5    AR-10
100 0.46    0.50    0.54    0.61    0.17    0.25
90  0.45    0.48    0.53    0.59    0.18    0.25
80  0.43    0.47    0.51    0.58    0.19    0.27
70  0.41    0.45    0.49    0.57    0.21    0.30
60  0.39    0.44    0.48    0.55    0.25    0.35
50  0.37    0.42    0.46    0.54    0.30    0.44
40  0.35    0.40    0.44    0.52    0.38    0.57
30  0.33    0.37    0.42    0.51    0.50    0.71
20  0.29    0.34    0.39    0.48    0.63    0.87
10  0.24    0.29    0.34    0.45    0.78    1.04
0   0.18    0.23    0.29    0.41    0.92    1.22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{p2.dat}{\2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
cycle list name=my black white,
title={Compressing Pressure: 0.2 MPa},
enlarge x limits=-1,
xmin=0, xmax=100,
xlabel={Water Saturation($S_w$)},
xtick={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
xticklabels={0,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100},
scaled ticks=true,
ymin=0, ymax=0.7,
ylabel={Avg. ETC \quad $\frac{K_{eff}}{K_s}$ $(Dimensionless)$},
legend style ={ at={(0.25,0.4)},
    anchor=north west, draw=none, font=\normalsize,
    fill=white,align=left},
smooth
]

`
\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCX-5}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{eff(x)}-Overlap \quad 5\% $};

\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCY-5}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{eff(y)}-Overlap \quad5\% $};

\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCX-10}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{eff(x)}-Overlap \quad10\% $};

\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCY-10}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{eff(y)}-Overlap \quad10\% $};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

The smoothness of the curves is not consistent. I was wondering if there is a way to use the `hobby` package and use the data in `.dat` file to produce smooth curves. The way I see it `hobby` uses absolute coordinates for drawing and not data points

Comment: I don't quite see why you need smoothing here at all, to be honest. Would it represent your data better to add (artificial) curvature to the plots?
 Unrelated note: Your legend entries should probably be of the form `$K_{\mathrm{eff}(x)}$ -- Overlap 5\% `, and in the ylabel, you don't want `Dimensionless` in math mode, so remove the dollar signs around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the manual for the `hobby` library, it supports use with `pgfplots`. It's just a matter of adding `\usetikzlibrary{hobby}` to the preamble, and saying e.g.

```
\addplot +[hobby] {rnd};
```

Hence, replacing `smooth` in your code with `hobby` works.

That said, I wouldn't do this myself, there is hardly any change from the default linear interpolation.

Note the changes I made to legend entries and ylabel as well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9, every tick label/.append style={font=\normalsize}}


\pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{my black white}{%
    solid,smooth, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=white}, mark=triangle*\\%
    solid, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=black}, mark=triangle*\\%
    densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=white},mark=diamond*\\%
    densely dashed, every mark/.append style={solid, fill=black}, mark=diamond*\\%
}

\begin{filecontents}{p2.dat}
SAT ETCY-5  ETCX-5  ETCY-10 ETCX-10 AR-5    AR-10
100 0.46    0.50    0.54    0.61    0.17    0.25
90  0.45    0.48    0.53    0.59    0.18    0.25
80  0.43    0.47    0.51    0.58    0.19    0.27
70  0.41    0.45    0.49    0.57    0.21    0.30
60  0.39    0.44    0.48    0.55    0.25    0.35
50  0.37    0.42    0.46    0.54    0.30    0.44
40  0.35    0.40    0.44    0.52    0.38    0.57
30  0.33    0.37    0.42    0.51    0.50    0.71
20  0.29    0.34    0.39    0.48    0.63    0.87
10  0.24    0.29    0.34    0.45    0.78    1.04
0   0.18    0.23    0.29    0.41    0.92    1.22
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{p2.dat}{\2}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
cycle list name=my black white,
title={Compressing Pressure: 0.2 MPa},
xmin=0, xmax=100,
xlabel={Water Saturation($S_w$)},
xtick distance=10,
ymin=0, ymax=0.7,
ylabel={Avg. ETC \quad $\frac{K_{\mathrm{eff}}}{K_s}$ (Dimensionless)},
legend style ={ at={(0.25,0.4)},
    anchor=north west, draw=none, font=\normalsize,
    fill=white,align=left,
    cells={anchor=west} %% <-- added
},
hobby
]


\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCX-5}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{\mathrm{eff}(x)}$ -- Overlap 5\% };

\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCY-5}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{\mathrm{eff}(y)}$ -- Overlap 5\% };

\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCX-10}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{\mathrm{eff}(x)}$ -- Overlap 10\% };

\addplot  table [x={SAT}, y={ETCY-10}] {\2};
\addlegendentry{$K_{\mathrm{eff}(y)}$ -- Overlap 10\% };

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```